# How to allow non-admins (Subscriber) to use certain WordPress plugins

Tags: php, wordpress

is there a possibility to set the user permissions for a plugin? I want an subscriber to use my custom plugin, but not give him all Admin rights.

Regards,
Pravin

Answer (score 1):

By using [user role editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) plugin you can give access to subscribe to use wordpress plugin

Comment: Already i used this plugin(user role editor) it was not working. Is there any function to solve this.

Comment: I want allow Subscriber to use my custom WP plugin without any other plugins.

Comment: yes its possible with add admin menu capabilities. You can give access to subscriber users for some plugin/admin menu